# How to delete files older than 7 days, with specific filename or file extension

Tags: php, database-backups, unlink

I have a index.php script that runs every night to backup a mySQL database (through CRON) on my website. The script store the file in the folder where the script is. I wanted to created another script that would delete backup files older than 7 days. So I used this one from tdebatty on GitHub:

```
<?php

function delete_older_than($dir, $max_age) {
  $list = array();
  
  $limit = time() - $max_age;
  
  $dir = realpath($dir);
  
  if (!is_dir($dir)) {
    return;
  }
  
  $dh = opendir($dir);
  if ($dh === false) {
    return;
  }
  
  while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
    $file = $dir . '/' . $file;
    if (!is_file($file)) {
      continue;
    }
    
    if (filemtime($file) < $limit) {
      $list[] = $file;
      unlink($file);
    }
    
  }
  closedir($dh);
  return $list;

}


// An example of how to use:
$dir = "/my/backups";
$to = "my@email.com";

// Delete backups older than 7 days
$deleted = delete_older_than($dir, 3600*24*7);

$txt = "Deleted " . count($deleted) . " old backup(s):\n" .
    implode("\n", $deleted);

mail($to, "Backups cleanup", $txt);
```

The script works well, but I would like to limit deletion to files starting with "XXX' or .sql.gz files. In the backup folder i have all the .sql.gz backup alongside the index.php script that is used daily to backup. This index.php file is not modified as the days go by, so it gets older and it is deleted by the deletion script at some point.

Thank you !

I tried to modify existing if conditions: `if (!is_file($file) || strpos($file, "XXX") !== 0) {` or `if (filemtime($file) < $limit && strpos($file, "XXX") === false) {` or `if (pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'sql.gz' && filemtime($file) < $limit) {`

I also tried to add another if condition in the loop:

```
if (strpos($file, "XXX") !== 0) {
        continue;
    }
```

None of these works and I don't understand why. Script doesn't work anymore, nothin happens. Any clue? Sorry if it's obvious, I'm still learning :)

Comment: This would be much easier to do in bash, using the `find` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here your mistake, the script redefine `$file` with this `$file = $dir . '/' . $file;` and you create a condition `strpos($file, "XXX") !== 0`, so your condition will like this `strpos("/YOURPATH/XXX", "XXX") !== 0`

Also you create this condition `pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == 'sql.gz'` is wrong because output of `pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)` is only extension (`gz`,`txt`,etc)

Here the working code

```
function delete_older_than($dir, $max_age, $prefix = null, $extension = null) {
  $list = array();
  
  $limit = time() - $max_age;
  
  $dir = realpath($dir);
  
  if (!is_dir($dir)) {
    return;
  }
  
  $dh = opendir($dir);
  if ($dh === false) {
    return;
  }
  
  while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
    $fullpath = $dir . '/' . $file;
    if (!is_file($fullpath)) {
      continue;
    }
    
    if ($prefix !== null && !(strpos($file, $prefix) === 0)) {
      continue;
    }
    
    if ($extension !== null && !(strlen($file) - strlen($extension) == strrpos($file,$extension))) {
      continue;
    }
    
    if (filemtime($fullpath) < $limit) {
      $list[] = $fullpath;
      unlink($fullpath);
      echo "Deleted $fullpath \n";
    }
    
  }
  closedir($dh);
  return $list;
}
```

For testing, use this code for generate a random file.

```
// Function for generate random file for testing only
function randomFile($extension) {
    $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    $filename = $randomString . $extension;
    return $filename;
}
function generateFile($extension, $prefix = '') {
    

    $directory = '/tmp'; // The directory path where the files will be created
    //$extension = ".sql.gz"; // The desired file extension

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        $filename = $directory . '/' . $prefix . randomFile($extension); // Construct the file name
        $content = 'This is file number ' . $i; // Content to be written in the file

        // Create the file and write the content
        file_put_contents($filename, $content);

        echo "File created: $filename \n";
    }
}
```

Then use it

```
generateFile(".sql.gz","XXX");
generateFile(".sql.gz","IAMUNDELETED");
generateFile(".txt");
sleep(1);
delete_older_than("/tmp", 0, "XXX","");
print_r(scandir("/tmp"));
delete_older_than("/tmp", 0, "",".txt");
print_r(scandir("/tmp"));
```

Here live code test : https://onlinephp.io/c/3fc02

Comment: Many thanks for this detailed explanation! Great for me as a learner 

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried str_contains()?

str_contains(string $haystack, string $needle): bool

```
if(filemtime(...) < $time && str_contains($file, 'XXX')) {
   unlink
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. I found a workaround based on extension, see my answer above. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

An acquaintance found the issue: when targeting by extension type, in my case file extension is "gz", not "sql.gz".